# Nginx 403 forbidden on static files using link_secure with grafana

Tags: nginx, grafana

I am trying to configure auto login using nginx as auth proxy, I am successfully able to authenticate but my problem comes when grafana loads all static files are 401.

my nginx configuration

```
#i also tried /grafana by enabling it in the grafana.ini  
  location / {
        secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
        secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri enigma";
        if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
        if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Session-Token $http_x_session_token;
        proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER $arg_user;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";
        #rewrite ^/auth(.*)$ /$1;       
                            
    }
```

[image: 404 errors]

as you can see all of resources are 401
below is link that i use for authentication

```
http://localhost/?md5=JSyq8fW04y5L7Khd0BoZ9g&expires=1686614400&user=admin
```

Comment: Maybe you need to forward the options to localhost:3000 by replacing proxy pass with with following: proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$is_args$args;

Comment: i tried still the same 403